# How to setup and use modem?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, modem

How do you setup and use Huawei EC169 CDMA USB  modem in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that modem is supported by ubuntu you can just set it up through the network manager specific instructions will depend on the network you're trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/) script, whose only real dependency seems to be you have the `ppp` package installed on your system.